# How can I annotate a Grouped Broken Barh Chart Python Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I have searched to exhaustion trying to annotate my grouped broken barH chart. I would like to have the "Event" from my dataframe annotated in each broken bar section. The examples I have found online manually enter the events x,y positions, AND, are not grouped broken bar examples.

the end goal is to have these events display on-hover, but I believe I wont have an issue if I can just get the events to display.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import io
pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()

inp = u""" T29,11/4/2019 0:00,11/4/2019 0:00,off,none
T29,11/4/2019 0:00,11/5/2019 0:00,off,eventa
T29,11/5/2019 0:00,11/6/2019 0:00,on,none
T35,11/4/2019 0:00,11/5/2019 0:00,off,eventb
T35,11/5/2019 0:00,11/6/2019 0:00,paused,eventa
T43,11/4/2019 0:00,11/4/2019 4:01,on,none
T43,11/4/2019 4:01,11/4/2019 12:06,off,none
T43,11/4/2019 12:06,11/5/2019 8:07,on,eventc
T43,11/5/2019 8:07,11/5/2019 10:12,paused,eventd
T43,11/5/2019 10:12,11/5/2019 16:15,on,none
T43,11/5/2019 18:12,11/5/2019 20:15,off,none
"""

mydateparser = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(inp), header=0, encoding = "ISO-8859-1", parse_dates=['StartTime', 'FinishTime'], date_parser=mydateparser, names=["Name", "StartTime", "FinishTime", "Status", "Event"])
color = {"on": "g", "paused": "yellow", "off": "black"}

df["Diff"] = df.FinishTime - df.StartTime
minDate = (datetime.datetime.toordinal(min(df.StartTime)))
maxDate = (datetime.datetime.toordinal(max(df.FinishTime)))
days = mdates.DayLocator()
Mcount = 0

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 3), edgecolor="black", linewidth=1)
labels = []
for i, task in enumerate(df.groupby("Name")):
    Mcount += 1
    labels.append(task[0])
    for r in task[1].groupby("Status"):
        data = r[1][["StartTime", "Diff"]]
        ax.broken_barh(data.values, (i - 0.4, 0.8), edgecolor="black", alpha=1, linewidth=1, 
                        color=color[r[0]])

ax.set_ylim(bottom=-0.8, top=Mcount)
ax.set_yticks(range(len(labels)))
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
ax.set_ylabel("Names", rotation=90, fontdict={'family': 'DejaVu Sans', 'color': 'black', 'weight': 'bold', 'size': 14})

ax.set_xlim(left=minDate, right=maxDate)
ax.set_xlabel("Date", fontdict={'family': 'DejaVu Sans', 'color':  'black', 'weight': 'bold', 'size': 14})

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%d-%Y'))
ax.tick_params(which='major', axis='x', rotation=0, length=11, color='black')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(days)

ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
ax.tick_params(which='minor', rotation=0, labelsize=8, length=4, color='red', size=2)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(.50))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you take a look at this? https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/horizontal_barchart_distribution.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-horizontal-barchart-distribution-py

Comment: I will break this down tomorrow and see if I can make this work for me. I have the additional complexity of the broken bar / xaxis specific locations+lengths. I am so stumped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. IIUC, you can append a for loop to your enumerate statement to add text to the axes.

```
for i, task in enumerate(df.groupby("Name")):
    Mcount += 1
    labels.append(task[0])
    for r in task[1].groupby("Status"):
        data = r[1][["StartTime", "Diff"]]
        ax.broken_barh(data.values, 
                       (i - 0.4, 0.8), 
                       edgecolor="black", 
                       alpha=1, 
                       linewidth=1, 
                       color=color[r[0]]
                      )

        for x1, x2 in data.values:
            ax.text(x=x1 + x2/2, 
                    y=i,
                    s=r[1]["Event"].values[0], 
                    ha='center', 
                    va='center',
                    color='white',
                   )
```

Modified from the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/horizontal_barchart_distribution.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-horizontal-barchart-distribution-py).

Output:
[image: Output of full code with above additions]

You can, of course, modify the text formatting.

The `text` requires an x location, a y location, and a string. The hacky indexing was the quickest way I could pull the event info out of your dataframe.

Comment: Flawless victory to you my friend. My logic was good in my previous attempts, my  syntax was not. This has taught me where i went wrong.Thank you.